# Calling EJB3 (jBoss7) from Mule 3.4

Tags: ejb, jboss7.x, ejb-3.0, mule, mule-studio

I am starting to work with Mule 3.4, and its IDE. I have to migrate some services from jBossESB to this Mule. Some of those services called EJB3 deployed on a external jBoss7, like this:

```
private ServiceInterface lookupRemoteEJB3Stateless() throws NamingException {
        final Hashtable<String, String> jndiProperties = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES,"org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
        final Context context = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);
        ServiceInterface myService = (ServiceInterface) context
                .lookup("ejb://URI/ServiceRemote");
        return myService;
    }
```

Also, I had a `jboss-ejb-client.properties` file in `src/main/resources`.

How should I approach this under Mule? Just copying code between servers is not working.. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This code should be working within Mule.

Did you add the necessary dependencies in your POM? Thinking JBoss client here.